# Changing source branch for PR on Github

Tags: git, github

I accidentally created a pull request from the master-branch of my fork of a repo.

While trying to rebase it I noticed that all of these changes were pushed into that pull request — due to the fact that you can simply `Add more commits by pushing to the master branch on username/repo`

- **Can you change the source branch of a pull request *after* the pull request has been submitted?**

I see you can edit the base branch, but that's obviously not what I'm after.

Comment: More correctly, any changes to the target branch of a PR are automatically included in the PR.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot change the source branch after creating a Pull Request. You have to create a new one instead.

For future reference, the established best practice is to create a new branch before making any commits. You should not commit directly to master, especially when contributing to team projects.

**Side note:**

> you can simply Add more commits by pushing to the master branch on username/repo

More correctly, any changes to the target branch of a PR are automatically included in the PR.

Comment: You can change the base branch after a creating a pull request. You just have to used the edit button

Comment: @TheGeorgeous as far as I can see you can only change the destination branch not source

Comment: base branch = target branch (thats always a bit confusing), thats the one you can change. Unfortunately not the source branch ( != base branch)

Comment: @Asara I don't understand your comment. Are you suggesting that I edit my answer? What changes are you suggesting?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it was just a clarification, because different terms where used in the comments here and they are sometimes misleading no-advanced users.

Comment: @Asara Yes, my terminology seems to be completely inaccurate and misleading. I need to fix this answer to be more inline with GitHub terminology. The comments need to be cleaned up to remove any additional confusion.

Answer (score 7):

Since you can't change the source branch in github (you can only change the target branch), you need to update the source-branch "inplace".

This answer contains three ways of doing this.

In Github you see:

> githubuser wants to merge N commit into master from "source-branch"

Since you will change the history of "source-branch", be sure nobody else is using this branch!

---

## Rewrite history of source-branch

If you are the only one developing on this branch, then you can use `git rebase -i` and later `git push --force-with-lease`.

This way you can rewrite the history of this branch.

Docs about rewriting the git history: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

---

## Rename temporary branch to source-branch

If you prefer to start from scratch.

```
git checkout master

# create a temporary branch
git checkout -b tmp-branch

... now modify the tmp-branch the way you want to. Commit, but don't push.

# rename tmp-branch to "source-branch"
git branch -f -m source-branch

# Be sure nobody is using "source-branch", since the history gets rewritten.
git push --force-with-lease
```

---

## git rebase --onto

Imagine your branch "source-branch" was accidentely based on "release" and not on "master". But the github target branch is "master". This way you can change your changes to be on top of master:

```
git checkout source-pr
git rebase --onto master release
```

Comment: That doesn't really solve anything if the source branch was set to master.

Answer (score -23):

[image: Screenshot 1][image: Screenshot2]

Yes we can edit the base branch/source after creating the pull request in the right hand side you get edit option see screenshot 1 attached, click on that and then you will be able to change base/source branch refer more on screenshot 2 attached with this comment

Comment: As you see in your screenshot you can change just the BASE branch.

Comment: 'source' branch means which branch you want to merge into the base branch (or 'target' or 'destination' branch) And github won't allow you to change that.

Comment: I don't mean any harm but I suggest deleting this answer.

Comment: Funny but even though it's not the answer to *this question*, it was exactly what I was looking for.