# Git change the source branch of a pull request

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-rebase, pull-request

Instead of making changes in another branch and making a pull request from that branch, i made the changes in the master branch and made the pull request.Now, i want to edit the pull request.

- I want to copy the changes made to the master branch to another branch.
- I want the master branch be updated with the upstream branch
- I want to update my pull request so that the commits are now made from the other branch rather than my master branch.
  Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing source branch for PR on Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381557/changing-source-branch-for-pr-on-github)

Answer (score 5):

> I want to update my pull request so that the commits are now made from the other branch rather than my master branch.

I'm afraid this is not possible.
The GitHub interface only allows to change the destination branch<sup>*</sup> to merge into,
not the source branch.

<sup>* This was added in [2016 August](https://github.com/blog/2224-change-the-base-branch-of-a-pull-request). I find the title of the announcement misleading, because what they call the "base branch", is the branch to merge into, not the source branch to merge from. I don't know if there are plans to add support for this.</sup>